# Loss gets stuck after undetermined number of epochs in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN model for image matting in Keras. I've tried different models and the problem keeps occurring. After starting the training, after some number of epochs, loss becomes 0.3385 and after it gets to this point, the loss never changes.
After this happens I interrupt the training and start over. Sometimes this solves the problem and sometimes doesn't. Also when this happens I look at the predictions and the output is all black. Normally it should've give me some grayscale matte.

I've tried disabling callbacks, it didn't work. I've trained a model 100 times, then i saved it. Then i loaded it to train another 100 times. The loss didn't get stuck in the first 100 epochs. Can this be related with the problem? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

```
Epoch 144/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 35ms/step - loss: 1.0376e-04 - val_loss: 0.3642
Epoch 145/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 35ms/step - loss: 1.0175e-04 - val_loss: 0.3642
Epoch 146/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 36ms/step - loss: 0.2364 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 147/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 35ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 148/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 36ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 149/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 35ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 150/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 35ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 151/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 36ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 152/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 34ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 153/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 35ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
Epoch 154/200
50/50 [==============================] - 2s 36ms/step - loss: 0.3385 - val_loss: 0.3640
```

And this is my model:

```
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((3, 3))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_image, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: You always do 100 epoch, then do another 100 and then get stuck the loss?

Comment: What is your learning rate?

Comment: @AhmadMoussa it's 0.001.

Comment: @Geeocode I don't always do 100. I trained the model for 100 epochs and i wanted to do another 100. After some epochs, it gets stuck.

Comment: Perhaps you run into the [dead ReLU problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/5706/56666). Do you use full batch training? One thing to try is to use Leaky ReLU or ELU activation instead. Also from your log the loss seems to go up from epoch 145 to 147, so maybe a smaller learning rate would do as well.

Comment: Try reducing the learning rate (For example use the magic learning rate: 2e-5 ) as you're probably overshooting the global minima.

Comment: It sounds you get stuck in a local minima because of a too large learning rate or/and optimizer for that lr. Furthermore if you loading a pretrained model you have to start the next 100 epoch with setting well the lr again, because there are technics for adjusting learning rate in a retrainnig but it is a more advanced technique what you have to study a bit more.

Comment: @a_guest I use batch size of 25. I will try using Leaky ReLu or Elu. But this problem doesn't occur when I traing model from scratch. I also  want to add that I also tried training vgg-16 from keras.applications.VGG16 with imagenet weights and without top layers. Then I added a couple of layers and upsampling layers. And it happened again. Loss gets to 0.3385 and never changes.

Comment: If you want to do image matting, shouldn't you use a sigmoid as your output non-linearity?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi I have tried that before. But research papers generally use relu if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Well for example this one (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03872) uses no non linearity for the last layer. I guess it just depends on which lies your output. If it's R, then no non linearity is probably a good choice, for [-1; 1] or similar you should probably go for sigmoid. I am not familiar with image matting so I just looked at the first paper for an example.

Comment: The reason I am suggesting this is because of the description the output you gave. If it's all black it's probably because the ReLU is zeroing a lot of it.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Im running into the same issue, loss gets stuck 0.6931 consistantly. No matter the model, no matter the learning rate.

Comment: @AkashBasudevan Why is that a "magic learning rate"?

Comment: @NelsonGon Well, you can try it when your models don't converge :P , they magically converge using that. One of my friends literally improved over 50 ranks on Kaggle just by using that. TBH this learning was used in BERT model and they(google) probably tried a lot of different numbers and finalized this one. Nothing magical as such. Just worth a try.